# Custom views with UIPanrecognizer unintendetly locks UITableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, nib, uipangesturerecognizer, ibdesignable

I would like to place custom views (created from nib) inside `UITableViewCell`s. That works without issues, unless the custom view declares it's own single touch `UIPanrecognizer`. In those cases my custom view responds to the pan events, but that pretty much disables the ability to scroll the cells inside the table view. I tried registering the UIPanRecognizer with both the cell and the custom view, but that ability seems to be not allowed any more since IOS 9 (seems like this is also not how Apple wants touch events to be handled, I read somewhere that touch events should just be handled by one view)

I also failed to find a way to scroll the table view programmatically, which would also seem a little hacky.

What are my options when it comes to wanting to preserve the pan behaviour of the UITableView while still being able to respond to a pan event inside my custom view?

My use case is as follows: I want to reuse a custom view that can sideways-scroll that I created for another part of my app. My table view is set to only react to downward pans. Therefore the two pan actions are not interfering.

Two ways I have this solved currently are as follows:
The sideways scroll reacts to two-finger pans. This is super awkward and unintuitive.

All gestures on the custom view (except taps) get sent to its superview. A tap on the custom view disables the rerouting, which locks the table view and enables sideways scrolling by letting the custom view react to the sideways pan. Another tap restores the initial behavior. This is awkward since it asks the user to perform three separate actions for what should be just one.

I know that I can enable sideways panning for table views, but that doesn't solve my problem of wanting to reuse my custom view inside the cell.

Does anyone know a solution to this dilemma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a custom `UIGestureRecognizer`.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/104744/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-creating-custom-recognizers), created a custom `SidewaysPanGestureRecognizer`, registered that instead and passed all gestures but `SidewaysPanGestureRecognizer` to the superview by implementing the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method responsible for deciding if the view should handle the gesture:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, 
     shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return gestureRecognizer is SidewaysPanGestureRecognizer
}
```